# SQL request and loop through result best pattern

Tags: java, sql, performance, design-patterns

I didn't really know  a good title for this but I'm asking myself what would be considered "good" for the following scenario

```
Table Place:
id | name | address | etc
```

```
Table Tag:
id | tag_name | score
```

```
Table Place_Tag
id | place_id | tag_id | numberX
```

For example, my application allow a user to search a place based on a tag. the result should contain the name of the place as well as the top 3 tag for that place (ordered by numberX)

My question is what is the best way to achieve this in Java using SQL ?

```
1) Select p.name, t.tag_name FROM Place p 
LEFT JOIN ... GROUP BY p.name,t.tag_name ORDER BY p.id,pt.numberX DESC
```

And then in Java I loop though the result (note the ORDER BY p.id) create some logic to only get the top 3 tag and when I detected that the n+1 id is different that means I'm processing the next place..

```
2) places = SELECT DISTINCT p.name FROM..... ORDER BY p.id
   tags = SELECT ... FROM Place_Tag pt WHERE pt.place_id IN (places.ids)
```

I make two separate SQL call one to get the places one to get the tags and then I find some kind of logic to link both together in Java

```
3) (this is the easier but I think the worst)  
   places = Select p.name FROM Place...
```

and then I loop through places and make a call to the database to get its tag (meaning if I loop trough 100 place I will make 100 extra call everytime..)

```
4) ? any other pattern ?
```

Could someone with more experience alive me on this?

Thank you!

Comment: If you can do it with one query, you should do so.

Comment: My preference would be to do the whole thing in SQL. No business logic in the program side, as much as possible. This allows the server to optimize the joins if it can. But really, this is an opinion-based question.

Comment: I agree with bot of you, I'm not an expert nor don't have a lot of experience with SQL but my instinct tells me to make as much as I can in SQL (Join, sort etc...) but then this implies sometimes that the Java on the other side will get more complicated logic to parse the data. So I was not sure what is usually done  by others

Answer (score 0):

Doing as much as possible on the SQL Server side will mean less data having to travel over the network from the database server to the application server.

This should be close enough to your scenario, though I'm bringing the top 3 tags for each place. To get the top 3 based on a tag search just add a `Where`.

Here's a fiddle with it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/54

Firstly I will create the tables and add data for the example:

```
DECLARE @Place TABLE (
    id int
    , name varchar(10)
    , address varchar(20)
)
DECLARE @Tag TABLE (
    id int
    , tag_name varchar(10)
    , score int
)
DECLARE @Place_Tag TABLE (
    id int IDENTITY (1,1)
    , place_id int
    , tag_id int
    , numberX int
)

INSERT INTO @Place VALUES (1,'place1','add1')
INSERT INTO @Place VALUES (2,'place2','add2')
INSERT INTO @Place VALUES (3,'place3','add3')
INSERT INTO @Place VALUES (4,'place4','add4')

INSERT INTO @Tag VALUES (1,'tag1',3)
INSERT INTO @Tag VALUES (2,'tag2',2)
INSERT INTO @Tag VALUES (3,'tag3',5)
INSERT INTO @Tag VALUES (4,'tag4',4)
INSERT INTO @Tag VALUES (5,'tag5',1)
INSERT INTO @Tag VALUES (6,'tag6',5)
INSERT INTO @Tag VALUES (7,'tag7',3)
INSERT INTO @Tag VALUES (8,'tag8',2)
INSERT INTO @Tag VALUES (9,'tag9',3)
INSERT INTO @Tag VALUES (10,'tag10',4)
INSERT INTO @Tag VALUES (11,'tag11',1)
INSERT INTO @Tag VALUES (12,'tag12',4)

INSERT INTO @Place_Tag VALUES (1,1,14)
INSERT INTO @Place_Tag VALUES (1,2,19)
INSERT INTO @Place_Tag VALUES (1,3,7)
INSERT INTO @Place_Tag VALUES (1,4,12)
INSERT INTO @Place_Tag VALUES (2,5,1)
INSERT INTO @Place_Tag VALUES (2,6,15)
INSERT INTO @Place_Tag VALUES (3,7,7)
INSERT INTO @Place_Tag VALUES (3,8,6)
INSERT INTO @Place_Tag VALUES (3,9,2)
INSERT INTO @Place_Tag VALUES (3,10,9)
INSERT INTO @Place_Tag VALUES (3,11,11)
INSERT INTO @Place_Tag VALUES (3,12,3)
```

And the query. There is a subquery which partitions by place and, as it orders by numberX descending, will allow the outer query to get the top n tags, based on numberX, for each place:

```
Select Sub.name, Sub.tag_name
FROM (
    SELECT p.name
        , t.tag_name
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.id ORDER BY pt.numberX DESC) rowNum
    FROM @Place p
    LEFT JOIN @Place_Tag pt ON p.id = pt.place_id
    LEFT JOIN @Tag t ON pt.tag_id = t.id
) Sub
WHERE Sub.rowNum <= 3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I didn't know about this "OVER (PARTITION BY" ! it looks VERY useful !!.

Comment: Indeed, windowing functions can be awesome:) [this is nice intro](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-2012-window-function-basics/) before going to the [technet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)